# Can I make modular classes of widgets while using setState?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a simple app which has a button ("Button!") that, when pressed makes a container ("Button Pressed!") appear and disappear.
I would like to refactor my code so that I have a MyButton class and MyPopup class, but I am running into a problem where I cannot call _setPressed in GestureDetector so I do not know how to make such a functionality work.

Is it possible to write code in this style, or does anything which involves state have to be declared together?

Here's the original:

```
/**
 * MyHomePage stuff
 */
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool pressed = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _setPressed();
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 36.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: Colors.lightGreen[500],
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Button!'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(  visible: pressed,
        child: Container (
          height: 36.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
              color: Colors.amber[500],
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Button Pressed!"),
            ),
          )),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _setPressed() {
    setState(() {
      pressed = !pressed;
    });
  }
}
/* end MyHomePage */
```

Here's more or less what I want it to look like:

```
/**
 * MyHomePage stuff
 */
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool pressed = false;
  Widget popup = MyPopup();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyButton(),
        MyPopup(),
      ],
    );
  }

}
/* end MyHomePage */

/**
 * Popup stuff
 */
class MyPopup extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyPopupState createState() => _MyPopupState();
}

class _MyPopupState extends State<MyPopup> {
  bool pressed = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return Visibility(
            visible: pressed,
            child: Container(
              height: 36.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
                color: Colors.amber[500],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Button Pressed!"),
              ),
            ));
  }

    void setPressed() {
    setState(() {
      pressed = !pressed;
    });
  }
}
/* end popup */

/**
 * MyButton stuff
 */
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            popup.setPressed();
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 36.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: Colors.lightGreen[500],
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Button!'),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
/* end MyButton */
```

[image: Button Pressed]
[image: Button Pressed again]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep the functionality of showing the pop up in your main class. What I meant is you can have two separate classes to render two widgets which is namely `Button` class that renders `button` in your screen and `Popup` class that renders the `Container` in your screen.

Then should you be showing the pop up based on the tap action, you should keep this logic in you main class.

Here is the code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool pressed = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            _setPressed();
          },
          child: MyButton(),
        ),
        MyPopup(isPressed: pressed),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _setPressed() {
    setState(() {
      pressed = !pressed;
    });
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 36.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        color: Colors.lightGreen[500],
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Button!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPopup extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isPressed;

  MyPopup({this.isPressed});

  _MyPopupState createState() => _MyPopupState();
}

class _MyPopupState extends State<MyPopup> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.isPressed,
      child: Container(
        height: 36.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
          color: Colors.amber[500],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Button Pressed!"),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Initially, in your main class

```
pressed = false
```

And in the build function while rendering the `MyPopup` class this variable is passed to the `MyPopup` class.

When you tap the button, you are setting the `pressed` variable in the `_setPressed` function inside a `setState`.

When `setState` is called it will rebuild the `build` method. So your `build` method in the main class will be called again with

```
pressed = true
```

Now `MyPopup` will be rendered again with `pressed = true` passed to it.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what this line does " MyPopup({this.isPressed}); "? I experience with Java, but these constructors look rather different so I'm having trouble understanding. Additionally, how does MyPopupState have access to the isPressed variable?

Comment: This is the named constructor. It means, the `MyPopup` class has a member variable `isPressed` and it's getting assigned with the Constructor `MyPopup()`.

Comment: For more on the named constructor, please follow this link: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors

Comment: > Additionally, how does MyPopupState have access to the isPressed variable?

Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * MyHomePage stuff
 */
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool pressed = false;
  Widget popup = MyPopup();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      provider: [ 
      ChangeNotifierProvider<Status>.value(
      value: Status(),
      )],
      child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyButton(),
        MyPopup(),
      ],),
    );
  }

}
/* end MyHomePage */

/**
 * Popup stuff
 */
class MyPopup extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    final _status = Provider.of<Status>(context);
    return Visibility(
            visible: status.isDisplayed,
            child: Container(
              height: 36.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
                color: Colors.amber[500],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Button Pressed!"),
              ),
            ));
  }

    void setPressed() {
        status.setIsDisplayed(!status.isDisplayed);
  }
}
/* end popup */

/**
 * MyButton stuff
 */
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    final _status = Provider.of<Status>(context);
    GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            status.setIsDisplayed(!status.isDisplayed);
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 36.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              color: Colors.lightGreen[500],
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Button!'),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
/* end MyButton */

class Status extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isDisplayed = false;
  bool get isDisplayed => _isDisplayed;
  void setIsDisplayed(bool value) {
     _isDisplayed = value;
     notifyListeners(); 
}
```

You would have to install Provider library which is a state management library for Flutter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to handle state within your HomePage, you can pass onTap function to your custom button and setstate on tap, and by passing the pressed variable to popUp it will be updated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/**
 * MyHomePage stuff
 */
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool pressed = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyButton(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              pressed = !pressed;
            });
          },
        ),
        MyPopup(
          pressed: pressed,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
/* end MyHomePage */

/**
 * Popup stuff
 */
class MyPopup extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool pressed;

  const MyPopup({@required this.pressed});
  _MyPopupState createState() => _MyPopupState();
}

class _MyPopupState extends State<MyPopup> {
  Widget build(BuildContext) {
    return Visibility(
        visible: widget.pressed,
        child: Container(
          height: 36.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.5),
            color: Colors.amber[500],
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Button Pressed!"),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
/* end popup */

/**
 * MyButton stuff
 */
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onTap;

  const MyButton({@required this.onTap});
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: this.onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 36.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          color: Colors.lightGreen[500],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Button!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
/* end MyButton */
```

---

Another solution is to use state management such as BLOC or Provider or MobX....
Simply you can notify any widget by changes happen in any widget.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain or point me to information about how widget.___ works? I haven't seen that before, and I guess I'm still a little confused as to how Stateful objects work with 2 classes.

Comment: That's how statefulwidgets works, they consist of 2 classes (one that extend the statefulwidget, the other is the state class), To access the "pressed" variable in "MyPopup" class from the state class "_MyPopupState" you need to call widget."variablename" which is "pressed" in our case so you can just consider it as if it were MyPopup.pressed

Actually, in your case MyPopup doesn't need to be statefulwidget you can just change it to a stateless widget instead